# Upload Data to Appspot Deployment "Authentication Failed"

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a python app on my local app engine dev server using the 1.7.1 SDK. I frequently load data into it using appcfg.py and upload_data with csv data files and remote_api. (It works great!)

I have now deployed the app to Google App Engine appspot.com under a gmail account without any errors and selected (Federated) OpenID to be used for end user login.

However, when I try to upload data to the deployed app using appcfg.py, I get an "[INFO ] Authentication Failed" error.

I have googled for several days now looking for solutions, but I'm finding conflicting suggestions. Nick Johnson has an [old workaround](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication) on his blog, but more recently people have reported it does not work. The SDK's appcfg.py supports an --oauth2 option now, but I can not find concise instructions on how to use it from a command line batch file -- besides the documentation says it does not work with upload_data.

I have [submitted this problem as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8133&thanks=8133&ts=1347719082) to the Google App Engine issue tracker.

I use the --no_cookies command line option. Per Google's suggestion, I tried again after switching my app from OpenID to the Google Accts API, but that failed too.

Does anyone know the current and preferred (working!) method to upload CSV data to a deployed python app? I don't think that uploading data to a deployed app is an "edge case", is it?!

Comment: Try the `--no_cookies` option, which forces `appcfg` to ask for credentials every time.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I already use that command line option and have added it to my original question for clarity.

Comment: Update: I found some (2 yr?) old forum entries that mentioned pre-pending the app id with "s~", so the command line would include a flag like, "--application-s~myappname". (It would be helpful if the Google docs included this detail!) So at least I'm able to upload some data while the app's authentication is set to use Google Accts. However, the original problem remains: What is the currently supported method to upload data to an app that is set to use OpenID?